# Repeating this toggle again on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a toggle set up that works great for what I am using it for. However I wish to have it work again on the same page, yet all my efforts end the same. Typically when I try to alter this set up only one out of the two display and will not toggle. Or will toggle only once and it seems to overwrite the second div to display nothing at all.

The HTML

```
<div class='navipart'>
<div><h3><p align='center'><a id='show_one' style='color:#EFE66E;cursor:pointer;'>One</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;&nbsp;<a id='show_two' style='color:#EFE66E;cursor:pointer;'>Two</a></p></h3></div>
<div>
<div id='one' class='current'>
</div>

<div id='two'>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

The below is what I want to add but am having issues with.

```
<div class='navipart'>
<div><h3><p align='center'><a id='show_three' style='color:#EFE66E;cursor:pointer;'>Three</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;&nbsp;<a id='show_four' style='color:#EFE66E;cursor:pointer;'>Four</a></p></h3></div>
<div>
<div id='three' class='current2'>
</div>

<div id='four'>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

This is the JS that I have. I am showing you the one that works when I only have divs one and two working. My attempts at messing with the JS have been a mess of code and non working :

```
$(window).load(function(){


$('p a').click(function(){

    var id = $(this).html().toLowerCase();

    $('.current').fadeOut(400, function(){
        $('#'+id).fadeIn(400);
        $('.current').removeClass('current');
        $('#'+id).addClass('current');

    });

});


});
```

This is the little bit of CSS that goes with it:

```
#two {display:none;}
#four {display:none;}
#live {display:none;}
#live2 {display:none;}
```

Just to recap exactly what I am looking for here. I would love to be able to have the top div toggle between 1 and 2, while having the bottom div toggle between 3 and 4 WITHOUT interfering with the other toggle effect. I did look through question that relate to mine, but most are code specific or have a different effect besides a simple div toggle. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I have been stumped on this for a few weeks now. 
Thank you in advance to those that read through this question. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Use the following structure. [**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/arvo188d/)

HTML

```
<div class='navipart'>
  <a href='#one'>One</a>
  <a href='#two'>Two</a>
</div>

<div class="naviitems">
  <div id='one' class='current'>
    Content of the first div
  </div>
  <div id='two'>
    Content of the second div
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navipart {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.navipart a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #EFE66E;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 30px;

}
.naviitems div {
  display: none;
}
.naviitems div:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

JS

```
$('.navipart a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr("href");
  console.log(id);
  $('.naviitems div').hide();
  $('' + id).fadeIn(400);
  $('.current').removeClass('current');
  $('' + id).addClass('current');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above, except with your original code...

```
<div class='navipart'>
<div>
<h3>
  <p align='center'>
    <a id='show_one' style='color:#EFE66E;cursor:pointer;'>one</a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a id='show_two' style='color:#EFE66E;cursor:pointer;'>two</a>
  </p>
</h3>
</div>
<div>
<div id='one'>
  One Block
</div>
<div id='two'>
  Two Block
</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript

```
$(function(){
  $("#one").show();
   $('p a').click(function(){
     var id = $(this).text();

     $('.current').fadeOut(400, function(){
      $('#'+id).fadeIn(400);
      $('.current').removeClass('current');
      $('#'+id).addClass('current');

     });

  });
});
```

And finally, The CSS

```
 #one, #two {
     display:none;
   }
   .current{
      display:block;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aaronfranco/j6bzq5pj/1/